# How to express the polynomial in an graded lex (with the descending power of multiple variables)?

Tags: sympy

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import A,B,C,D,E,F,x,y,U,V,W,X,Y,Z

curve = A*x**2+B*x*y+C*y**2+D*x+E*y+F
```

Now that we know such codes above will form the polynomial `curve` like
$$A x^{2} + B x y + C y^{2} + D x + E y + F$$
However, the six terms of the polynomial are sorted only relevant to the upper cases. To be sure of this, we could just substitute the coefficients like:

```
curve.subs({A:Z, B:Y, C:X, D:W, E:V, F:U})
```

And then the output polynomial comes to be totally out of the order of `x, y` like
$$U + V y + W x + X y^{2} + Y x y + Z x^{2}$$
Then, we know that class `Poly` can be used to pull `x, y` out, making the terms of the polynomial arranged only by the times of `x` and `y`, and arrange `x` first, then arrange `y` when the terms include `x` to the same power.

```
Pcurve = curve.as_poly(x,y)
```

$$\operatorname{Poly}{\left( A x^{2} + B xy + D x + C y^{2} + E y + F, x, y, domain=\mathbb{Z}\left[A, B, C, D, E, F\right] \right)}$$

The way to keep sorting is easy, just redefine `x` and `y` via

```
x,y = symbols('\ x, \ y')
```

where the spaces with the smaller ASCII code of 32, give the `x` and `y` priority. However, like the `Poly` result,  `x` and  `y` are not in the same priority. the  `x` is preferred.
$$ x^{2} Z +  x  y Y +  x W +  y^{2} X +  y V + U$$

Then, how to just collect the terms, while the times of `x` and `y` can be treated together, to make $Xy^2$ in front of $Wx$, while the terms are sorted by the preferred `x, y`, which are presented after the coefficients?

---

In fact, what I really did is

```
x,y = symbols('\ \ x, \ \ y')
x0, y0 = symbols('\ x_0  \ y_0')


# dpp = Symbol('(x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2')
dpp = sqrt((x-x0) ** 2 + (y-y0) ** 2)
dpl = (A * x + B * y + C)

elps = x**2 / a**2 + y ** 2 / b ** 2 - 1
Lagrange = Add(dpp ** 2, - e ** 2 * dpl ** 2, - lamda * elps, evaluate=False)
Lpoly = Poly(Lagrange, (x,y))
Lag_exp = Lagrange.expand()
Lag_coll = Lag_exp.collect([x,y])
```

Where the last four variables are assigned by

1.
$$- e^{2} \left(  x A +   y B + C\right)^{2} - \lambda \left(\frac{  x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{  y^{2}}{b^{2}} - 1\right) + \left(\left(  x -  x_{0}\right)^{2} + \left(  y -  y_{0}\right)^{2}\right)$$

2.
$$\operatorname{Poly}{\left( \frac{- A^{2} a^{2} e^{2} + a^{2} - \lambda}{a^{2}}   x^{2} -  2 A B e^{2}   x  y + \left(- 2  x_{0} - 2 A C e^{2}\right)   x + \frac{- B^{2} b^{2} e^{2} + b^{2} - \lambda}{b^{2}}   y^{2} + \left(- 2  y_{0} - 2 B C e^{2}\right)   y +  x_{0}^{2} +  y_{0}^{2} - C^{2} e^{2} + \lambda,   x,   y, domain=\mathbb{Z}\left(a, b, e,  x_{0},  y_{0}, A, B, C, \lambda\right) \right)}$$

3.
$$-   x^{2} A^{2} e^{2} +   x^{2} - \frac{  x^{2} \lambda}{a^{2}} - 2   x   y A B e^{2} - 2   x  x_{0} - 2   x A C e^{2} -   y^{2} B^{2} e^{2} +   y^{2} - \frac{  y^{2} \lambda}{b^{2}} - 2   y  y_{0} - 2   y B C e^{2} +  x_{0}^{2} +  y_{0}^{2} - C^{2} e^{2} + \lambda$$

4.
$$  x^{2} \left(- A^{2} e^{2} + 1 - \frac{\lambda}{a^{2}}\right) +   x \left(- 2   y A B e^{2} - 2  x_{0} - 2 A C e^{2}\right) +   y^{2} \left(- B^{2} e^{2} + 1 - \frac{\lambda}{b^{2}}\right) +   y \left(- 2  y_{0} - 2 B C e^{2}\right) +  x_{0}^{2} +  y_{0}^{2} - C^{2} e^{2} + \lambda$$

---

And my ideal order for the letters are: `x` = `y` > `a` = `b` = `A` = `B` > `C` > `e` > `λ`. The normal 'lex' or 'inv-lex' (`Lagrange.expand().as_ordered_terms('rev-lex')`) both do not fit me.

---

I had a simple and crude way to realise MY goal, but still not a general solution. Could it be enhanced?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import A,B,C,D,E,F,a,b,e,x,y,lamda
x0, y0 = symbols('x_0  y_0')

dpp = sqrt((x-x0) ** 2 + (y-y0) ** 2)
dpl = (A * x + B * y + C)
elps = x**2 / a**2 + y ** 2 / b ** 2 - 1

Lagrange = dpp ** 2 - e ** 2 * dpl ** 2 - lamda * elps
Lexpd = Lagrange.expand()

standard_curve = A*x**2 + B*x*y + C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + F

Ldict = {}
for i in [x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y]:
    coeff = Lexpd.coeff(i)
    if len(coeff.as_terms()[0]) > 1: 
        Ldict[standard_curve.coeff(i)] = '\\left(' + latex(Lexpd.coeff(i))+ '\\right)'
    else: 
        Ldict[standard_curve.coeff(i)] =  latex(Lexpd.coeff(i))
    Lexpd -= Lexpd.coeff(i) * i
Ldict[standard_curve.coeff(1)]= latex(Lexpd.expand())

print(latex(standard_curve, symbol_names=Ldict))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314035/force-sympy-to-keep-the-order-of-terms Is this relevant to your question?!

Comment: Could the indexing scheme $A_2^1x^2 + A_2^2xy + A_2^3y^2 + A_1^1x + A_1^2y + A_0$ work? It should sort as $A_2^i \geq A_1^i \geq A_0$, i.e. by powers.